# Is there an easy way to clone an existing chosen select box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Able to clone the dropdown with values. It's working fine in the first row but when I click the glyphicon for cloning the another row the dropdown control froze (Nothing happened).

```
@Html.DropDownList("searchfieldsDropdownList", new SelectList(Model.DataDictionary, "ID", "BLSName"), "", new { @class = "**chosen-select**" })

$("**.chosen-select**").chosen();

$(".glyphicon-plus").click(function () {
    $(this).closest("tr").clone(true).appendTo("#ruleTable");});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the plugin on the new select after you insert it

Something like:

```
$(".glyphicon-plus").click(function () {
   var $row = $(this).closest("tr").clone(true).appendTo("#ruleTable");
   $row.find('.chosen-select').chosen()
});
```

Comment: When I clicked the second row dropdown but it is displaying the first dropdown values only.

Comment: OK...took some playing around. Here's a working version with a few comments  https://jsfiddle.net/mL4trwut/2/